# css3 animation help needed why doesn't this animate?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where I am trying to animate a picture of a mouse hovering over the page and moving around. But I cant get the stupid thing to work, and it doesnt seem to be throwing up any immediate errors. 
 [code here:](http://pastebin.com/T9xPHfY2)

Can someone point me in the right direction? What is wrong with this css? Why isnt it animating the image?

Comment: Please provide a demo rather than just links to external resouces holding code. If the links break your question becomes useless.

Comment: man, you post code here, and ppl are like oh use pastebin. Use pastebin and someone gonna show up an say use jdfiddle. aint nothing ever gonna be good for posting code. Does stack overflow have a code post section I should know about?

Comment: @j0h Put the code *in the question*, and possibly provide a JSFiddle (or similar) link *as well*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not specify any dimensions for the `div` so it has no size for the background to show through.

Also, you do not need to repeat the `background-image` declaration on every line of the keyframe definition.

```css
div {
background-image: url('http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/mouse.png');
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: myfirst 5s;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation: myfirst 5s;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@keyframes myfirst {
0% {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
25% {
    left:200px;
    top:0px;
}
50% {
    left:200px;
    top:200px;
}
75% {
    left:0px;
    top:200px;
}
100% {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
0% {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
25% {
    left:200px;
    top:0px;
}
50% {
    left:200px;
    top:200px;
}
75% {
    left:0px;
    top:200px;
}
100% {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```